# Reusing the same NgModule with different config

Tags: angular, ng-modules

I want to build a generic module that I can pass some config to customize it. For example, in the root module I want to have something like

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        moduleFactory(config1),
        moduleFactory(config2),
        moduleFactory(config3)
    ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The `moduleFactory` will return a module with routes that will be constructed based on `configx` objects. These modules will provide some views that will show customized content based on the config object. How can I do that?

Comment: there's a way to do that using `ModuleWithProviders`, but if you put some logic that requires runtime execution into `moduleFactory`, it won't work with AOT

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com The main problem I am having is just with AOT. Now I have only the main `NgModule` defining the routes, and in the route config array I call a function that returns a route object config and when I run `ng serve` I got an error:  Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'admin', function calls are not supported. 
Is it worth giving up AOT to have less code? I don't understand AOT very well and I don't know the benefits to use it.

Comment: yeah, that's expected, static analysis doesn't evaluate the code. No, it's not worth giving up AOT. The compiler takes around 40% of the Angular code that you ship to a browser which is not shipped with AOT and with pre-compiled components you also get startup time boost

Comment: Thanks for taking your time

Comment: sure, good luck) check out [angularindepth](https://blog.angularindepth.com/) publication, there's a wealth of in-depth information there

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com I came up with a solution and posted as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution using `loadChildren`. In the main route config I have something like this:

```
{
    path:'companies',
    loadChildren: 'app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule',
    data:{
        // the config1
    }
},

{
    path:'users',
    loadChildren: 'app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule',
    data:{
        // the config2
    }
}
```

Then, in the `AdminModule` I can read the `data` property. Besides, I was trying to define absolute route paths in `AdminModule` routes, but now, with the `loadChildren` solution, I can define relative paths, therefore I can have the routes defined statically and AOT just works :). I have something like this in the `AdminModule` routes:

```
{
    path: '',
    component: TablePageComponent,
},
{
    path: 'item',
    component: FormPageComponent,
}
```

With that, I can load the users table with the route `/users` and a specific user with the route `/users/item;id=1`. The same applies to the companies and whatever else.